# JetBrains Java issues with Generics

Tags: java, generics, ide, jetbrains-ide

I am using the newest JetBrains IDE and with Java 14.

With the following declaration of the generic type

```
    A<Integer> a1 = new A<Integer>();   //Good

    A<String> a2 = new A<String>();    // Good 

    A<Integer> a3= new A<>();   // Error
```

It doesn't allow me to make this declaration IT give me an Error... I think it has something to do with the Project Setting/Project Structure etc...

I just don't know what it is... can someone help... I saw this declaration on a video and it compiled on the video and I asked and the response was it should be in the settings... but he couldn't tell me what to change.

Peter Fraga

Comment: Is your [project language level](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-page.html) set to at least Java 7 (that's when the [diamond operator](https://howtodoinjava.com/java7/improved-type-inference-in-java-7/) was added)?

Comment: I am using Java 14, unless their is another place ... like I said,,, earlier...                        

A<Integer> a3= new A<>();   // Error

This Diamond Operator is not working .... according to wht I have seen and read it should take the value from other declaration    and I should be able to use ...                                

A<Integer> a3= new A<>();       

maybe you can show me if I need to change,   thank you ...

Peter Fraga

Comment: It's not necessarily about what version of Java you're using but rather what your _project language level_ is set as. And I linked to the official documentation of IntelliJ.

Comment: Hi I found the Program Language java 14...
I check and although it marks an error I was able to compile and actually the sample program ran... I even recompiled with different value and it ran...  

It musk be some kind of setting issue... 

Thanks 

Peter Fraga

Comment: Also check the project language level of [your IntelliJ module(s)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/modules.html). If you're using something like Maven or Gradle, make sure they're configured for the version of Java you're targeting—IntelliJ typically synchronizes with the build tool being used.

Comment: proj. language  is java 14. in modules etc... I believe I am not using Maven... not sure how to check... I selected the Project which MAven is an option I select Java...